# I am flying to Macau from Michigan and would like to take a kilo of frozen Cured Canadian Bacon

Tags: food-safety

The flight is roughly 20 hours.Will it still be safe to eat once I arrive in Macau?

Comment: Food safety concerns aside, bear in mind you have to obtain permission to bring meat products into Macau in the first place: https://macau.visahq.com/customs/

Answer (score 2):

Here is the customary seasoned advice answer: [How do I know if food left at room temperature is still safe to eat?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/34670/how-do-i-know-if-food-left-at-room-temperature-is-still-safe-to-eat)

The variables in your case:

- you are starting out frozen (not refrigerated or room temp)
- we don't know the temps of the cargo hold
- or are you carrying it onboard (where temps are higher)

You could wrap in foil and make it within temp safety limits... but that can be foiled (pun) by airport security after x-ray, because they'll unwrap that foil to see what's inside.

Bottom line:

- when in doubt throw it out, food poisoning is awful
- leave the Canadian Bacon at home. It's not going to fly safely.

Comment: If you do want to try to make something like this safe, you pretty much need an ice chest (or a makeshift version): enough insulation and other cold stuff (ice or cold packs) to keep it below 40F/5C.

Comment: Good point. Dry ice and a styrofoam cooler come to mind. But it may put it beyond the OP's $$ available.